# How to locate M values in ArcGIS Silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, linear-referencing, silverlight

I am trying to work with M values in the Silverlight API.

I gather that the IdentifyParameters would be used to identify a milepost by clicking along the line, but what would I use to query an M value so the app could zoom to it upon a user-entered value?

To be clear, I am looking for a function quite like an address locator, but for M values.

Comment: The topic to look for is linear referencing and there are existing Q&As here (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/is-there-an-existing-way-to-do-linear-referencing-in-arcgis-javascript-api-2-1 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6660/how-can-i-do-client-side-linear-referencing-in-an-esri-silverlight-wpf-app) but I am not sure if either provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks, @PolyGeo.  I think you referenced my own post in that first link, but I have seen the second one.  It's a few years old.  I have a feeling that solution is unnecessary since M values are supported at ArcGIS for Silverlight 3.  I just don't know how in this particular instance.

Comment: Oops - I've modified the link to put the one I meant instead but as you say if M values are supported in the ArcGIS API for Silverlight now then it sounds like it is just a case of needing an answer on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks again, @PolyGeo.  I see the first link now.  I think I can do this without a server call or geoprocessing service, etc.  As I mentioned in the original question, it looks like Identify returns M values: click on the line and it returns the milepost.  However, I need the opposite: give a milepost and the app will show the point along the line.

Comment: Yep - that's linear referencing (aka dynamic segmentation and previously chainage) in ArcGIS for Desktop terminology.  Unfortunately, I do not have ArcGIS API skills to help with this one.